# Вырезать все символы кроме цифр

Tags: php, парсер

Здраствуйте, столкнулся с такой проблемой, у меня есть статьи, которые я получаю парсингом с другого сайта, вот код:

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('https://game-tournaments.com/dota-2/news');
$pos = strpos($content, '<div class="box nlist">');
$content = substr($content, $pos);
$pos = strpos($content, '<nav class="pull-right">');
$content = substr($content, 0, $pos);
$content = str_replace('','', $content);
echo $content;
?>
```

И на сайте, чтобы прочитать статью полностью нужно перейти по ссылке.
Проблема в том, что мне нужно вытянуть с каждой ссылки цифры, вот код с которого нужно вытянуть:

```
<h2><a href="/dota-2/news/39825"
```

39825 - цифры меняются з каждой статьей и мне нужно их вытянуть с ссылки.

Попробуйте с моим кодом, а если что-то не так прошу подправить меня, спасибо

Comment: Вот, тег парсер есть, а парсера нет, дилемма... Воспользуйтесь им и не нужно будет возиться со строками

Answer (score 0):

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://game-tournaments.com/dota-2/news');
preg_match_all('/news\/(\d{1,})\"/', $content, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

При этом можно не отрезать части полученного html, а просто искать эту ссылку.
Приведенный код вернул такие данные:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => news/39830"
            [1] => news/39825"
            [2] => news/39823"
            [3] => news/39822"
            [4] => news/39821"
            [5] => news/39819"
            [6] => news/39815"
            [7] => news/39814"
            [8] => news/39811"
            [9] => news/39809"
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 39830
            [1] => 39825
            [2] => 39823
            [3] => 39822
            [4] => 39821
            [5] => 39819
            [6] => 39815
            [7] => 39814
            [8] => 39811
            [9] => 39809
        )

)
```

Вам нужен `$matches[1]` дальше его циклом перебирать и сохранять содержимое в файлы:

```
for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++){
    file_put_contents($matches[1][$i].'.html', file_get_contents('https://game-tournaments.com/dota-2/news/'.$matches[1][$i]));
}
```

Comment: Можете подсказать как перебирать?

Comment: А что должно дальше происходить с полученными значениями? Писать в файл или как-то обрабатывать? В чем вообще суть всего происходящего? Если нужно парсить эти ссылки для того чтобы потом отображать эти новости у себя на сайте - можно использовать другой подход

Comment: Я это делаю для того, чтобы создать файл с таким же числом и с другого сайта дополнялась вся статья в этот файл

Comment: Тогда что-то вроде такого:
`for($i = 0; $i < count($matches[1]); $i++){
    file_put_contents($matches[1][$i].'.html', file_get_contents('https://game-tournaments.com/dota-2/news/'.$matches[1][$i]));
}`

Очень не удобно в комментарии код приводить... Вообще, если нужно сохранять новости по файлам - лучше вытаскивать не цифры, а сразу полную ссылку

Comment: Дополнил ответ, добавил цикл для создания и записи в файлы